# Rheem heat pump burping every minute

Tags: heat-pump

I have a Rheem heat pump that is making a grunt sound every minute, even after the thermostat is set to off. At the same time it makes a 5k watt spike. Here is a video of it making the sound: https://photos.app.goo.gl/R3koaGemK97Mphaz8

Comment: looks/sounds normal, just speeding  up the fan

Comment: Why would it be doing that once every minute while it is set to off? Also when I'm at the circuit breaker I hear a buzz while the heat pump is causing this 5k watt spike.

Comment: Publish the electrical schematic so I can answer that

Comment: Turn off the circuit breaker. Wait at least an hour (or more - more is good.) Turn it back on. If the problem remains, turn it off and call for service.